# Confusion with arguments of complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help to decide which pair(s) among these three complex numbers are equal:

$z_1 = ae^{i\alpha}+be^{i\beta}$,

$z_2=ae^{i(\alpha+2\pi x)}+be^{i(\beta+2\pi x)}$,

$z_3=ae^{i(\alpha+2\pi x)}+be^{i(\beta-2\pi x)}$.

Where $x$ is an integer.

I only know all three have the same modulus and same principal argument. But I don't think they are all equal. I suspect that $z_1\neq z_2$ and $z_1=z_3$. But these are just wild guesses.

Background: I want to know this because I'm studying the $k^{th}$ root of such complex numbers.

Comment: Then $e^{i2\pi x}=1$ for any integer x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $e^{2\pi i n} = 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, since arguments of $0,\pm 2\pi,\pm 4\pi, \dotsc$ all correspond to the positive real axis. (Note, in that regard, that adding or subtracting $2\pi$ from an argument leaves the complex number exactly the same, as it corresponds to a full rotation).

Therefore, since $x$ is an integer, $z_1 = z_2 = z_3$.

Comment: Noted. But what about their $k^{th}$ root? Is it also $\sqrt(z_1)=\sqrt(z_2)=\sqrt(z_3)$?

Comment: The symbol $\sqrt{}$ isn't generally well-defined for complex numbers, since a complex number will have two square roots (or, in general, $k$ $k$th roots). With real numbers, $\sqrt{}$ is chosen to be the positive root, but with complex numbers, there's no such canonical choice.

Answer (score 1):

If two complex numbers have the same modulus and argument (modulo $2\pi$), then they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Use that for any integer $x$, $e^{i(\alpha + 2 \pi x)} = e^{i \alpha}$. You can see this by writing it out as $e^{i(\alpha + 2 \pi x)} = \cos(\alpha + 2 \pi x) + i\sin(\alpha +2 \pi x) = \cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha)$.